# Getting a relationship limited by the current user without generating N queries in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the web app I'm building I have a model called Task and another called TaskStatus. Tasks are global and have many TaskStatus which also belong to a user (many users perform the same tasks and the status track that).

I want to display all the tasks and access the status of that task belonging to the current user without generating N queries (one per task). Does Rails offer a way to achieve this? I've been playing with scopes and includes to no-avail.

I know of I could just run the second query manually and store them in a hash indexed by the task id, but I'm trying to find, if possible, a more railsy way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify this filter with a seperate association using conditions:

```
has_many :current_user_task_statuses,
conditions: { user_id: proc { current_user.id } },
class_name: "TaskStatus"
```

Then you can preload all the wanted TaskStatuses with a constant amount of queries like this:

```
Task.all.includes(:current_user_task_statuses)
```

I'm not absolutely certain that the proc will work in the conditions, but give it a try. If it doesn't, try this:

```
has_many :current_user_task_statues,
proc { where('user_id = ?', current_user.id) },
class_name: 'TaskStatus'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, that wouldn't work, Rails is lexically not dynamically scoped (otherwise I wouldn't use it) so an association doesn't have access to a controller method/helper.

Comment: Ah, that's true. Then I'm out of ideas.